# flask slqalchemy Динамическая подстановка имени поля

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Flask + SQLAlchemy. Существует страница с большим количеством однотипных форм (тестирование), сериализация формы через AJAX, проблема в том, что формы генеруются динамически (form_1, form_2 и т.д.) из-за их однотипности. Каждой форме соответсвует запись в таблице БД. Проблема в так и не смог найти, как подставить имя поля в маршурутах динамически.

```
@app.route('/check', methods=['POST'])
def check():
    form = Form()
    if request.method == "POST":
        field = request.form.get('answerField')
        ans_number = 'task_' + request.form.get('answerNumber')
        answer.ans_number = field
```

Соответственно, атрибута ans_number в таблице не существует, он должен быть значением этой переменной.
Есть ли штатные средства SQLAlchemy или использовать sqlite?
В перспективе будет переход на MySQL, поэтому sqlite - не вариант.

Comment: А что такое `answer`? Это какой-то объект таблицы?

Comment: это и есть имя таблицы.

Comment: Разобрался сам. Это нужно делать через setattr(), всё работает. Не силен я в ООП, надо подтягивать.

Comment: Тогда, пожалуйста, оформите самостоятельно ответ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашел сам. Это было нужно сделать функцией setattr(obj,'attr', value),
где obj - имя модели flask, 'attr' - строка, которую можно генерировать (в моем случае в цикле), в которой записано имя поля модели, value - значение, которое мы хотим записать в поле.